# SICP: The non-strict or lazy `cons`, how does it work?

Tags: scheme, lazy-evaluation, sicp, cons

The following is an excerpt from the SICP book, Section [4.2.3 Streams as Lazy Lists](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-4.html#%25_toc_%25_sec_4.2.3):

> With lazy evaluation, streams and lists can be identical, so there is
>   no need for special forms or for separate list and stream operations.
>   **All we need to do is to arrange matters so that `cons` is non-strict.**
>   One way to accomplish this is to extend the lazy evaluator to allow
>   for non-strict primitives, and to implement `cons` as one of these. **An
>   easier way is to recall (section 2.1.3) that there is no fundamental
>   need to implement `cons` as a primitive at all. Instead, we can
>   represent pairs as procedures:**
>
> ```
> (define (cons x y)
>     (lambda (m) (m x y)))
> (define (car z)
>     (z (lambda (p q) p)))
> (define (cdr z)
>     (z (lambda (p q) q)))
> ```

**Question:** I don't see how the above definition of `cons` achieves lazy or non-strict behavior. For example, the following call to `cons`,

```
(define (foo) '(1 2 3))
(define bar (cons 'a (foo)))
```

does result in the invocation of `foo` at the point `cons` is called, which is a non-lazy or strict behavior.

So, how would we write a lazy or non-strict version of `cons` that is also not a *special form*.

Comment: The section presupposes that the code is evaluated by the lazy evaluator of the previous section, 4.2.2.

Comment: Hmm. I somewhat suspected what you're saying here to be the case,  but was not fully sure. E.g., the above section 4.2.3 motivates the problem faced in the earlier section 3.5.1 where special forms `delay` and `cons-stream` - the authors say - *had* to be necessarily used. This made it sound as if the authors are trying to get rid of special forms OUTSIDE of the evaluator in the current section 4.2.3.

Comment: @molbdnilo If you can repost your comment as a reply, I'll make it final.

Answer (score 1):

The section presupposes that the code is evaluated by the lazy evaluator of the previous section, 4.2.2. – [molbdnilo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/404970/molbdnilo), on [Mar 2 '17 at 7:49](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42546404/sicp-the-non-strict-or-lazy-cons-how-does-it-work#comment72234278_42546404).